# How to deprecate data associated with an R package?

Tags: r, package

I have developed an R package for managing data associated with a project. The packages is used only by people working on the project.

I would like to update one of the tables with some serious changes: I am changing the name of the table, changing the column names, and adding new columns. Some people are using the old version of the table and I would like to make the transition as smooth as possible. My desired outcome is to have a message printed to the console when the user loads a specific table with data(my_table) to inform them that an updated version is available under a different name.

I have tried adding .Deprecated() to the my_table.R script. This produces the desired warning message when the *package* is loaded, but I would like it to print when the specific data object is loaded (i.e., when the user runs data(my_table).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think this is possible, I'd only call `packageStartupMessage` in the `.onAttach` hook defined in your package, specifying that the data will change.